# 'Column Does Not Exist' when trying to INSERT JSON Array using json_to_recordset()

Tags: sql, node.js, arrays, postgresql, typescript

I am having an issue trying to INSERT the variable data within a JSON array into a postgresql table. I am trying to insert 2 variables: link_url and link_key into their own respectable columns.

I am using json_to_recordset() to capture the variables within the json array.

This is the table where I am attempting to insert the data:

```
CREATE TABLE support_url(
    support_url_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    link_url        VARCHAR(2100),
    link_key        INTEGER
);
```

This is my array structure:

```
support_url: { link_url:string, link_key:number }[]
```

This is the query I am trying to fulfill:

```
            `        
            INSERT INTO support_url
            (link_url, link_key)
            SELECT * FROM 
            json_to_recordset(support_url_array)
            AS x(link_url text, key_url int)
            WHERE support_url_array = $1  
            `
```

This is the whole code:

```
export async function saveSupportReview(
   
    support_url_array: { link_url:string, link_key:number }[] 

    ):Promise<any|any>{

    console.log('support_url_array:');
    console.log(support_url_array);

    const client=await pool.connect();
    
    try{
        const resp=await client.query(
            `        
            INSERT INTO support_url
            (link_url, link_key)
            SELECT * FROM 
            json_to_recordset(support_url_array)
            AS x(link_url text, key_url int)
            WHERE support_url_array = $1  
            `,
            [
                support_url_array
            ]);
        
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
    client.release();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
support_url_array:
[
  { link_url: 'dfdfdfdfdf', link_key: 1593590036764 },
  { link_url: 'hkh', link_key: 1593590038821 },
  { link_url: 'dvdvsbsfbsfbs', link_key: 1593590042120 },
  { link_url: 'khkhj', link_key: 1593590044831 }
]
error: column "support_url_array" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:413:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\GitFolder\roqq\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  name: 'error',
  length: 181,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42703',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '136',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'd:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_relation.c',
  line: '3359',
  routine: 'errorMissingColumn'
}
```

As you can see, support_url_array does exist as it is being printed:

```
support_url_array:
    [
      { link_url: 'dfdfdfdfdf', link_key: 1593590036764 },
      { link_url: 'hkh', link_key: 1593590038821 },
      { link_url: 'dvdvsbsfbsfbs', link_key: 1593590042120 },
      { link_url: 'khkhj', link_key: 1593590044831 }
    ]
```

However, just underneath, the error reads:

```
error: column "support_url_array" does not exist
```

I do not understand this error. Since support_url_array does exist and json_to_recordset does not receive a column,

Comment: The support_url_array is a variable in the function.  The sql statement you send to postgresql does not know anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this change.

```
    try{
        const resp=await client.query(
            `        
            INSERT INTO support_url
             (link_url, link_key)
            SELECT * 
              FROM json_to_recordset($1)
                    AS x(link_url text, key_url int)
            `,
            [
                support_url_array
            ]);
```